# Applying array as arguments to Date constructor

Tags: typescript

I am trying to construct a `Date` from a `string[]` with a variable number of elements -- sometimes 3, sometimes 6. However, the following Typescript code fails to compile:

```
const parts = ['1', '1', '2001'];
const dte = Date.apply(undefined, parts) as Date;
```

with:

> Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[]'.ts(2345)

Presumably the compiler is trying the `Date` constructor with no arguments, which I don't want. But even if the array is `number[]`, the compiler doesn't seem to find the right overload:

```
const parts1 = parts.map(x => parseInt(x,10));
dte = Date.apply(undefined, parts1) as Date;
```

How can I resolve this?

More specifically, how can I create a `Date` using the array of values as arguments to the constructor?

Comment: Date is a constructor function, which should use with new operator to generate a new date. https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, make sure you use numbers instead of strings. That's what the type signature says.

```
[1, 1, 2001]
```

Then, tell TypeScript what you just told us — that your list is not just any list of numbers (`number[]`), but a list of precisely 3 items or more.

```
type Sequence<T> = [T, T, T, ...T[]];

const parts: Sequence<number> = [1, 1, 2001];
```

All you need to do is create a `new Date`.

```
const dte = new Date(...parts);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Date constructor expects anywhere between 2 and 7 arguments. Since you are mapping an array with unknown size, you need to make sure that there are indeed specified number of args by providing defaults for the first 2. The snippet below should do the trick:

```
// Date constructor can have between 2 and 7 args
type DateArgs =
    [number, number, number?, number?, number?, number?, number?];

const parts = ['2000', '10', '10']
const args: DateArgs = [0, 0];
parts.forEach((part, index) => {
    args[index] = parseInt(part, 10);
})

console.log(new Date(...args));
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some good answers but if you are sure of the content of your array
there will be no issues, typescript wants to check everything so you just have to tell it 
I know what I am doing here.

Do this :

```
const parts = ['1', '1', '2001'];
const dte = Date.apply(undefined, <any>parts) as Date;
```

Or :

```
const parts = ['1', '1', '2001'];
// @ts-ignore
const dte = Date.apply(undefined, parts) as Date;
```

Comment: This code may compile, but it doesn't work. Because when `Date` is used as a function, and not as a constructor, everything past the first argument is discarded. Since `1` is not a parseable date, JS simply returns the current date. What's needed is some way to tell Typescript that my array has the right number of elements; and then, since Typescript supports destructuring an array into parameters, I can use that to put the elements into the `Date` constructor: `const dte = new Date(...parts);`.

Comment: yeah `Date.apply` is just like calling `Date()` gives you a string(current date) and not a Date object.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
const parts: [number, number, number] = [2001, 1, 1];
const date = new Date(...parts);
console.log(date); // Thu Feb 01 2001 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)
```

Comment: In my case, the array comes from the results of a regular expression, which may return 3 or more arguments.